# Copying and merging two files

Tags: java, file

I am using java File Streams. I have two files. First file may or may not be empty. The second file contains strings and floats. If the first file is empty then I want to copy second file in it. else I want to merge the files.

Have tried `RandomAccessFile` but it's not working.

Comment: Can you explain in what way you want to merge the files?

Comment: file 1 contains some words n file2 contains some so I want to make union of them.

Comment: So if a word exists in both file1 and file2, it should exist only once in the merged file, right? Another question: How large are the files?

Comment: absolutely right and the files may be having at max 10 lines

Comment: Right. What is the structure of the file - are the strings and floats associated with each other or are they completely independent?

Comment: Yes the strings and floats are associated.The floats indicates the weight of a string in a particular document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy a file then use

```
public static Path copy(Path source,
        Path target,
        CopyOption... options)
                 throws IOException
```

[File.copy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29)

If you want to merge them then open the file in write mode in which you want to append the data with appending mode.

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWritr(new FileWriter("file.txr",true));
```

and then write the data in `bw` which you have read from the source file.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would look like this:

```
public void CopyFile(File one, File two) throws IOException {

    // Declare the reader and the writer        
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(one));
    BufferedWriter out;

    String contentOfFileOne = "";

    // Read the content of the first file
    while(in.ready()){
        contentOfFileOne += in.readLine();
    }

    // Trim all whitespaces
    contentOfFileOne.trim();

    // If the first file is empty
    if(contentOfFileOne.isEmpty()){

        // Create a new Writer to the first file and a reader
        // from the second file
        in.close();
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(one));
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(two));

        while(in.ready()){
            String currentLine = in.readLine();
            out.write(currentLine);
        }

        // Close them accordingly
        in.close();
        out.close();

    } else {

        // If the first file contains something

        in.close();
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(one,true));
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(two));


        // Copy the content of file two at the end of file one
        while(in.ready()){
            String currentLine = in.readLine();
            out.write(currentLine);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();

    }
}
```

The comments should explain the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is supposed to be the most efficient option

```
    FileChannel f1  = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("1"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    FileChannel f2  = FileChannel.open(Paths.get("2"));
    f1.transferFrom(f2, f1.size(), Long.MAX_VALUE);
```